# Factoring out repetitive ItemsControl.ItemsPanel XAML code to a resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` repetitive XAML sections that I'd like to factor out to a Windows.resource. I've made an attempt at it for `RegionD` but I get a incompatible type error message. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<Window x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.ShellWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="150" Width="325" >

<Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl x:Key="IC" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionA" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionB" />
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionC" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="{StaticResource IC}" Grid.Row="2"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionD" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a Style with Setter for ItemsPanel:

```
<Style x:Key="IC" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>  
</Style>
```

then apply Style to each ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource IC}" Grid.Row="1"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionC" />
<ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource IC}" Grid.Row="2"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RegionD" />
```